What is the scope of the "keydown" and "onkeydown" tags? Web? Any platform?
The name of the keydown and onkeydown tags sounds very much like a direct reference to web APIs, namely keydown from DOM UI Events and onkeydown from HTML (both attribute and property). However, the blurb for each of these events doesn’t specifically mention web or anything else.
I saw keydown applied to this winforms question. That would make sense if these tags referred to a platform-independent general concept of an event which happens prior to "keyup", which might be called "keydown" or "KeyDown", or even onKeyPress (since a single event there has properties allowing it to respond to the down, repeat, and up phases). However, it would not make sense if this tag were a direct reference to Web APIs.
Which is it? Can these tags’ descriptions be clarified somehow?

"Can these tags’ descriptions be clarified somehow?" ¯\(ツ)/¯ we don't know what the intention was when they were created. Nor does it matter, because they are bound to have been used for other purposes. Like how you may have found out already. We can either add a description based on the current usage, or apply a more strict description which will require retagging to make the usage conform to the description.

The tags are overwhelmingly used for the Web API technology, although the oldest question currently around that uses them is a Silverlight technology.

"The name of the [tag:keydown] and [tag:onkeydown] tags sounds very much like a direct reference to web APIs" -- That is one interpretation. The name could also be a direct reference to Microsoft's Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs) Method. (Note: This event is not the same as "OnKeyPress".)

I don't see these tags existing in isolation. It's better to get rid of it, rather than try to steer rivers using traffic signs

Generically they apply equally to any UI that takes keyboard input. Gtk/Gdk, Qt, WxWidgets, etc... all have key handlers for them. Web UI or desktop UI would likely make a more logical categorization within which key handling (keydown, onkeydown) takes place. There is also an argument to make that as desktop UI move more and more to a one-size-fits-all mobile/desktop toolkit the less that distinction matters. key-handler may be a more appropriate catch-all.

I see no value in those tags, neither in having both of them, nor in having any of them. they're overly specific. their use falls under [tag:user-interface] or anything related to event handling or input devices.

The tags should be removed altogether. They do not provide a meaningful classification and are—more often than not—used to describe what the OP assumes to be the solution to their problem. The only purpose they serve is as a precursor to the "XY Problem". Burn them, with fire.

@ChristophRackwitz "Anything related to input devices" is far too generic and absolutely not useful as a tag. At best, they should be synonymised to [[tag:keyboard-events]].

@Bergi Questions tagged with key-whatever-events are predominantly the result of a misunderstanding of how input is processed. The pattern generally involves questions about keyboard events because the asker doesn't understand the broader picture, and the events aren't actually part of the solution. input-processing is a far superior classification.

@IInspectable Not sure what misunderstanding you mean. When someone asks about keyboard events, i.e. how to detect and handle key presses, they are not asking about processing file inputs, processing camera input, or processing stdin streams.

@Bergi Input gets processed. It doesn't just enter the system as a key-whatever-event. Seeing how hand-rolled input processing systems behave in web applications it seems that web developers are wildly unaware of this concept. Thanks for the confirmation.

@IInspectable I'm well aware, but people are not asking how the OS (or a native application) is processing user input. They are asking how to do it on their platform (or framework), and such input enters the web platform as key events, which is why the tag is natural and totally appropriate. If you're not a web developer, it may not matter to you.

@Bergi That's missing the "Y" part of the "XY Problem". I'll produce a list of questions where the OP asks for keyboard events but the actual solution involves other parts of the input processing pipeline when I get bored enough. This matters to any developer doing UI, including web developers (even if they insist that their framework of the week completely releases them from the need to understand its abstractions).
